# Count if rows in range have two criteria set

Tags: google-sheets

I cannot find a simple answer to this, sorry if this is super obvious.

I have a table:

```
        A        B
1       Fruit:   Rotten?
2       Apple    TRUE
3       Banana   FALSE
4       Apple    FALSE
5       Apple    TRUE
```

Now I would like to have the formula for:
=COUNT(of rotten Apples in range A2:B5)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward, you use COUNTIFS with multiple criteria

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A5; "Apple"; B2:B5; TRUE)
```